# How to parse words in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I was wondering how to parse a parragraph that looks like the following:

```
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
And many other lines with text that I do not need

                                    * * * * * * *

Autolisp - Dialect of LISP used by the Autocad CAD package, Autodesk,
Sausalito, CA.

CPL - 

  1. Combined Programming Language.  U Cambridge and U London.  A very
complex language, syntactically based on ALGOL-60, with a pure functional
subset. 

Modula-3* - Incoprporation of Modula-2* ideas into Modula-3.  "Modula-3*:
```

So I can get the following exit from the awk sentence:

```
Autolisp
CPL
Modula-3*
```

I have tried the following sentences because the file I want to filter is huge. It is a list of all the existing programming languages so far, but basically all the lines follow the same pattern as the above

Sentences I have used so far:

```
BEGIN{$0 !~ /^ / && NF == 2 && $2 == "-"} { print $1 }

BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} /^FLIP -/{print $1,$3}

BEGIN{RS=""; FS=OFS="\n"} {print $1 NF-1}

BEGIN{NF == 2 && $2 == "-" } { print $1 }

BEGIN { RS = "" } { print $1 }
```

The sentences that have worked for me so far are:

```
BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; FS = " - " }
{ print $1 }

awk -F " - " "/ - /{ print $1 }" file.txt
```

But it still prints or skips lines that I need/ don't need.

Thanks for your help & response!
I have broken my head for some days because I am a rookie with AWK programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `FS` should be fine, to avoid any duplicate lines you can pipe the output to `sort -u`

```
$ gawk '$2 == "-"  { print $1 }' file | sort -u
Autolisp
CPL
Modula-3*
```

It might not filter out everything you want but you can keep adding rules until the bad data is filtered.

Alternately you can avoid using `sort` by using an associative array:

```
$ gawk '$2=="-" { arr[$1] } END { for (key in arr) print key}' file 
Autolisp
CPL
Modula-3*
```

Comment: Thanks @Dru. It worked the 2 times I ran it without adding more rules. I will keep testing the sentence until I notice something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It worked almost perfectly. I just need to find out how to skip a few lines that it did not ignore and it will work like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: it seems like you're scanning:

Comment: Hey @Dru, how can I do in order to parse just the names of the programming languages, I have written : 2=="-" { arr[$1] } END { for ("-") print "-"} but I can't make it work. Thanks again :D

Comment: END { for el in arr; print el; |

Comment: What do you mean with "el" you mean "-" ? Thanks @Dru

Comment: the function each element of the array `arr` to the variable el. It is how to print an array.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be with awk, it would probably work to first use grep to select lines of the right form, and then use sed to trim off the end, as follows:

```
grep -e '^.* -' | sed -e 's/\(^.*\) -.*$/\1\n/; p;'
```

Edit: After some playing around with awk, it looks like part of your issue is that you don't always have '[languagename] - [stuff]', but rather '[languagename] -\n[stuff]', as is the case with CPL in the sample text, and therefore, FS=" - " doesn't separate on things like that.

Also, one possible thing to try is as follows:

```
BEGIN { r = "^.* -"; }
{
    if (match($0, r)) {
        printf("%s\n", substr($0, 1, RSTART + RLENGTH - 3));
    }
}
```

I don't actually know much about awk, but this is my best guess at replicating what the grep and sed do above. It does appear to work on the sample text you gave, at least.

Comment: Indeed @qaphla as you can see none of the above sentences do work for me, any suggestion to make this work?

Comment: I've added an awk script that should work, based on the little I know of it and some testing. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: I have tried your code but unfortunately for me I couldn't get the exit I need. It prints the following: Autolisp - Dialect of LISP used by the Autocad CAD package, Autodesk,1 . NEW LINE. CPL - 1. NEW LINE. Modula-3* - Incoprporation of Modula-2* ideas into Modula-3.  "Modula-3*. As you can see it is kind of "mixed"

Comment: That sounds like the results I was getting a bit further back in testing, before I had the text on this page in its final version. Are you sure the page is up to date? The code that should be displayed is 'BEGIN { r = "^.* -" } { if (match($0, r)) { printf("%s\n", substr($0, 1, RSTART + RLENGTH - 3)); } }'. If this is, in fact, what you're running, I'd check the version of awk, and also try playing around with the indices on substr to see whether it's working properly or not.

Comment: Oh no, you are totally right. I didn't notice you edited your reply @qaphla. The sentence I used was the following: BEGIN { r = "^.* -"; }
{
    if (match($0, r)) {
        print($0, 1) 
 RESTART - 3;
    }
}

Comment: Now using the code you updated @qaphla I got:  Autolisp - Dialect of LISP used by the Autocad CAD package, Autodesk,1 . NEW LINE. CPL - 1. NEW LINE. Modula-3* - Incoprporation of Modula-2* ideas into Modula-3. "Modula-3*:1. As you can see it is very similar to the first version of the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for your response and time @qaphla